# Java vs. HTML5 for Android Navigation App with Google Maps

Tags: java, android, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to develop a navigation app like "Find my Car" or something. For the navigation and the map i want to use the google maps api.
Now i must decide, which language i want to use. Java vs. HTML5.
I'm more familiar with Java, but in the Google Maps API documentation, it would be easier to develop with HTML5, is it?

The application must run on a android phone. So what is better to use: Java, which i'm more familiar, or with HTML5, which (i think) is easier to use in combination with Google Maps.

Hope you can help me, i must decide me in approximately one hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, I would not say that the answer is always Java. It actually depends on your needs, like always.

The great thing when you use HTML5 (you could try PhoneGap: http://phonegap.com/) is that it will work on multiple different systems, whereas a native Android app won't.

On the other hand, in a native App, you will be able to access to the whole Android API, and it will be more powerful as well.

As a conclusion, if you need a powerful app processing images in real time, you want a native application. But if you want something simple that could easily be rendered in HTML5 and you potentially will create the same application on a different system (say, IOS), then HTML5 will make you earn precious time.

And in the case where there is not a clear "good" way to follow, simply choose the one in which you are more comfortable: as long as you can create an application that answer your needs, it will be the most productive way.

And always keep in mind that it is possible to include a "WebView" in an Android native app, which means that you can have best of both worlds.

In your very situation, it seems that Android already has some nice features for using Maps (most probably better than the HTML5 version). That might help your decision.

Comment: What a answer! So the both of you would chose Java. And im more comfortable with java, so i'll use it too. Thank you also for that massiv substantiation!

Answer (score 2):

if you're developing an app (not game) in Android the answer is always Java! Always!

and implementing maps in Android in its native Java is as simple as 1.2.3 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: +1 Thank You! But I must justify my decision. So, why alway java? HTML5 provides a lot of multiplatform stuff?

Comment: I don't think HTML5 is as responsive as a native solution. About 1 year ago I participated in a project that tried to use HTML5 and phonegap for mobile mapping applications. It could never get close to the performance and overall user experience we had from a native application. Button clicks, no pinch-to-zoom and map panning and zooming are very slow and choppy. Like I said, this was about 1 year ago, but I can't say I've seen that much improvement in this past year.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your feedback! So i use Java. Thanks a lot.

Comment: everything @ebarrenchea said plus the fact that your question specific pointed to be an Android only app. Even if none of ebarrenchea points are concerns for this project, if you're only developing for Android, it's also much easier and better supported to developed with Java. Said that I don't believe user1368342 to be the best as it does answer in a very eloquent way something that you were not really asking.

Comment: @Budius: For me the best answer is the comment of embarrenchea. But the answer from user1368342 is for me also a really good overview about developing mobile apps with java or HTML5, because i never had develop a mobile app before, so i'm a big n00b. 
but your answer is also great! So the +1...

Answer (score 0):

Language, IDE, platform ... everything is tool. What will you use depend on the needs of your application. I work with both techniques. When you'll develop an application that uses many resources linked to hardware (eg accelerometer, gps...), it is advisable that you use a native language, it saves battery and you has the maximum advantage of the device, gaining in performance.

Now if you'll develop an application that uses few hardware resources, the most interesting solution is HTML5 (example: PhoneGap, SenchaTouch, Titanium, etc..).

In my years of experience, before deciding how to develop I wonder what I will develop, so as to see which one best meets my need!